# Hiding form submit button in loop

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using javascript to hide the post button until text has been entered into the form.  It works fine but when i have the form being rendered for each post in a loop it only works for the first post and the button isn't hidden for the rest.

Here is the javascript:

```
$(function(){
 $("#button").hide();

 $("#inputBody").keyup(function() {
     var val = $(this).val();
     if (val.length > 0) {
         $('#button').show();
     }
     else {
         $('#button').hide();
     }

 });
});
```

Here is the form:

```
<%= f.input :body, input_html: { :id => "inputBody" } %>
<%= f.submit "Answer", { :id => "button", class: "button5" } %>
```

and here is the view:

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
<%= question.body %>
<%= render :partial => "answers/form" %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the html for the first form in the loop vs the second.

```
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/questions/61-the-best/answers" class="simple_form answer" id="new_answer" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="opkAO1vlXgbqHebqee839dtFv1lsA/osUexmGTU2x7k=" /></div>
<div class="input text optional"><textarea class="text optional hello3" id="inputBody" name="answer[body]" placeholder="Answer" rows="1">
</textarea></div>
<input class="button5" id="button" name="commit" type="submit" value="Answer" />
</form>
```

Second (button is showing):

```
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/questions/62-this-is-a-test-question/answers" class="simple_form answer" id="new_answer" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="opkAO1vlXgbqHebqee839dtFv1lsA/osUexmGTU2x7k=" /></div>
<div class="input text optional"><textarea class="text optional hello3" id="inputBody" name="answer[body]" placeholder="Answer" rows="1">
</textarea></div>
 <input class="button5" id="button" name="commit" type="submit" value="Answer" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you give the output HTML (view source) of that code snippet for us non-rails people?

Comment: Edited. Sorry, its pretty messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you reuse the same id (inputBody) multiple times.  If you want to identify multiple similar elements, use a class.  Ids are supposed to identify a single element.

Try using inputBody as a class and $(".inputBody") to select it.  Apply the same principle to selecting the buttons.  One way to select the appropriate button is to look at the siblings of inputBody's parent.

Here's the JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4JDxS/

And the code snippet (just the javascript) for quick reference.  See the JS fiddle for the HTML changes:

```
$(function(){
 $(".myButton").hide();

 $(".inputBody").keyup(function() {
     var val = $(this).val();
     if (val.length > 0) {
         $(this).parent().siblings('.myButton').show();
     }
     else {
         $(this).parent().siblings('.myButton').hide();
     }

 });
});
```

Comment: Give me a second, I'll put together a better explanation.  The buttons need to not reuse the same ID as well.

Comment: Closer, except now both buttons show when text is entered into 1. (But now they are both hidden at start ). I made both inputBody and button5 classes instead of ids.

Comment: Ok, I think we have something closer to a real solution now.  I switched from my tablet to my laptop in the process.

Comment: Hmm, now the buttons aren't showing up at all with your new js.

Comment: Did you see the proof of concept in the JS Fiddle?  Notable changes from the HTML: inputBody was added to the class attribute in each form, and myButton was added to the class attribute on both buttons. Assuming nothing else changed about the HTML, it should work.  If you're confident you followed the changes in the JS Fiddle, could you show me your new HTML?

Comment: Aah there we go - missing the mybutton in the html. Thanks a lot for the help, i appreciate it!